# nginx directory listing on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, web-server, directory-listing

I searched a lot and everyone says add these in config file and it will work:

```
location /my_directory {
    autoindex on;
}
```

I opened **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file and added it under `http` but service did not start. Added it under `http -> server` and received `403 forbidden error`.

I have no idea about nginx. Can someone tell me easily about what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the:

```
location /my_directory {
    autoindex on;
}
```

In the file in your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory that corresponds to the virtual host your site is using. There is already a `server` block in the file, so you simply place the `location` block inside the `server` block.

Comment: I added `location` settings at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file and after restart (`service nginx restart`) it worked. Thank you.